# How to fix "object 'n' not found" using MASS library package in R?

Tags: r, kurtosis

I am trying to find the skewness for the variable galaxies in the MASS data library

I have outlined the formula for skewness, then loaded the MASS package, defined galaxies dataset, but get an error as n is undefined in the skewness formula. I am not sure if I need to include an n or not, as I just want my sample size to be all results in galaxies.

My code is

```
myskewness = function(x) {
  n = length(x)
  xbar = sum(x) / n
  myskewness = (sqrt(n) * sum((x - xbar)^3)) / sum((x -xbar)^2)^(3 / 2)
  return(myskewness)
}

gal <- galaxies

myskewness(gal)
```

> Error in myskewness(gal) : object 'n' not found

Comment: It works for me

Comment: Code works for me too. Have you tried restarting your R session & running this in a clean environment?

Comment: Yep still doesnt work